# ISNULL usage with NULL database fields

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, isnull

I am trying to do something that should be fairly simple but ISNULL isn't doing what I thought it would.

Basically I have a stored procedure and I am expecting either PARAM1 OR PARAM2 to have a matching value in my table.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE      
        field1 = ISNULL(@PARAM1 ,field1 )
        AND        
        field2 = @PARAM2
```

This works fine until I have NULL fields in my row then it excludes those results. Is there a different method that can cater for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISNULL replaces the first value with the second value, so only if your parameter @PARAM1 is NULL does it replace it with PARAM1.  I assume you're not passing in NULL values, so that's probably not what you want.  More likely you just want to say

```
WHERE
(Field1 = @PARAM1 OR Field1 IS NULL)
AND
Field2 = @Param2
```

I Suppose you could use ISNULL in this fashion too:

```
ISNULL(Field1, @PARAM1) = @PARAM1
```

Comment: No. The OP passes in either `@PARAM1` or `@PARAM2` and they are wanting the parameter that is `NULL` to effectively be a `No-OP`. Except it isn't as the act of doing `PARAM1 =` will exclude any rows where that column is NULL.

Comment: Param 1 or 2 can be null. I only pass in the param that I'm interested in and the other is set to NULL

Comment: Martin, that's what I was saying.  If the column value is NULL (as he says, "until I have NULL fields in my row"), the @PARAM1 (which won't be NULL) won't match it.  So he either needs to use ISNULL on the column value, or check to see if Param1 IS NULL.

Comment: Andi, if @PARAM1 or @PARAM2 can match, can't you just use OR instead of AND in your WHERE clause?

Comment: I can't because when param1 is null param2 takes a set value of for example 1234567. I know my question doesn't show this clearly. What works is the following: (Field1= @Param1 OR Field1 IS NULL) 
               AND (Field2= @Param2)  can you update answer and I'll mark as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
field1 = ISNULL(@PARAM1, A_REPLACEMENT_VALUE_IF_PARAM1_IS_NULL)
```

This will evaluate to-

field1 = @PARAM1 if @PARAM1 IS NOT NULL.

field1 = A_REPLACEMENT_VALUE_IF_PARAM1_IS_NULL    if @PARAM1 **IS NULL**

EDIT:

Try these:

```
--If you want to ignore the WHERE clause if PARAM1/2 is null
ISNULL(field1, DEFAULT_VALUE) = ISNULL(@PARAM1, ISNULL(field1, DEFAULT_VALUE))
OR
ISNULL(field2, DEFAULT_VALUE) = ISNULL(@PARAM2, ISNULL(field2, DEFAULT_VALUE))
```

OR

```
--To get all rows with field1/2 as PARAM1/2 and ignore everything else
field1 = @PARAM1 OR field2 = @PARAM2
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing though isn't it?

Comment: @Andi Try  ISNULL(PARAM1, DEFAULT_VALUE) = ISNULL(@PARAM1 ,DEFAULT_VALUE)

Comment: @Andi Why can't you just try PARAM1 = @PARAM1 OR PARAM2 = @PARAM2  ?

Comment: I've answered why to a dupe comment above :)

Comment: I still don't understand. What happens when field1 has a value and feild2 is NULL. May be an example would have helped. Anyway, glad that you found an answer.

Answer (score 1):

null is special in sql. If you do any comparisons on a column any rows that have a null for that column will be excluded.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE      
        (PARAM1 = @PARAM1 or PARAM1 is null)
        AND        
        (PARAM2 = @PARAM2 or PARAM2 is null)
```